# How to split a div into multiple rows and columns in css?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have div `subdiv` inside `maindiv`. I want to make the sub div into multiple rows and columns as below.

How to divide the `subdiv` as below

[image]

Comment: Should the "columns" always have the same height? What happens to the blocks if content is way longer/shorter in each of the 4 blocks? What content are they made of: images and/or text? EDIT: and what did you try so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this

```css
div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:40px;
}

.one{
  width:150px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
}

.two{
    width:100px;
  height:200px;
  background:lightgreen;
}

.three{
    width:100px;
  height:200px;
}

.four{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
background:darkblue;
}
.five{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="two">2</div>
<div class="three">
  <div class="four">4</div>
  <div class="five">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I know that the question has been answered but there is another way to do this.

You can Achieve it using css grid. [read more about css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
.grid { 
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 10rem 7rem 7rem 7rem;
    grid-template-rows: 7rem 7rem;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "s1 s2 s3"
    "s1 s2 s4"
}
.s1 { 
    grid-area: s1;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
.s2 { 
    grid-area: s2;
    background-color: #00FF36;
}
.s3 { 
    grid-area: s3;
    background-color: #0030FF;
}
.s4 {
    grid-area: s4;
    background-color: #FF00E4;
}
```

```html
 <div class="grid">
      <div class="g s1"></div>
      <div class="g s2"></div>
      <div class="g s3"></div>
      <div class="g s4"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

just copy paste the code into a file and save as .html, and run the page.

```css
/*Reset CSS*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/*Our custom css for this page*/

#container {
  width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#head {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  clear: both;
  height: 35px;
}

.subhead1 {
  width: 38%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #3CF;
  float: left;
}

.subhead2 {
  width: 13%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #3CF;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0% 0 2%;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100px;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3CF;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

#footer {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #3CF;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="head">
    <div class="subhead1">
    </div>
    <div class="subhead2">
    </div>
    <div class="subhead2">
    </div>
    <div class="subhead2">
    </div>
    <div class="subhead2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
  <div class="content" style="height:250px;">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just copy paste the code into a file and save as .html, and run the page.